# Way to match all files in a Finder search

Tags: macos, finder, file-search

I want to create a Finder saved search aka "Smart Folder" that matches all files in the subfolders of a certain folder, to create some sort of overview folder. Is there a certain search request that does the trick, something like the magic "*.*" search term in Windows?

A workaround would be to search for "NOT blabla" matching all files that are not named "blabla", but that doesn't feel so nice and robust to me.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

After pressing Command+F, hold down the alt key and the plus sing on the right of the search condition should change into ellipsis. Press it and add the condition "none of these are true: kind is folder". It should look like this:
[image: Finder showing all but folders]

Comment: this worked but the dot is simpler ;-)

Answer (score 2):

type DOT . in finder file search)))